# generalized function over static arrays in c

Tags: c

I have a few static arrays of structs of differing sizes, I wish to create a generelized function that populates these arrays, I would like the specific array to be populated to be a paramater of this function. What is the best way to do that ? (aside from avoiding the static arrays, sadly they can't be helped).

the (relevant bits of) code:

```
typedef struct{
    char ip[IP_LEN+1];
    char netmask[IP_LEN+1];
} ipAndNetmaskStruct; 
typedef struct{
    char port[PORT_LEN+1];
} portStruct;


static ipAndNetmaskStruct source[1024];
static ipAndNetmaskStruct dest[1024];
static portStruct source_port[1024];
static portStruct dest_port[1024];

//just an example of wha
void doSomthingWithStruct(the array and a specific field in each stcut in it){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        THEARRAY[i].SPECIFICFIELD="Somthing";
        // as in source[i].ip="somthing";
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it you don't just want to zero the arrays out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this ?

```
void doSomethingWithStruct(void* structptr,int ssize,int cnt, int offset,void* val,int vsize)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
   {
      //perhaps add bool as a function parameter to check if mem should be allocated ?
      memcpy( ((uint8_t*)structptr)+i*ssize+offset, val,vsize);
   }
}

//usage
typedef struct{
    char ip[IP_LEN+1];
    char netmask[IP_LEN+1];
} ipAndNetmaskStruct; 
static ipAndNetmaskStruct source[1024];
char data[IP_LEN+1];

doSomethingWithStruct(source,sizeof(ipAndNetmaskStruct),1024,/*if it was netmask it would have been sizeof(char)*(IP_LEN+1)*/0,data,IP_LEN+1);
```

EDIT:
you could use `offsetof` to get the offset of the member - defined in the "stddef.h", and in the spirit of that you could also use `#define sizeof_member(s,m) sizeof(((s *)0)->m)`

example:

```
#define doSomethingWithStruct(srcptr,type,member,val) doSomethingWithStruct(srcptr,sizeof(type),sizeof(srcptr)/sizeof(type),offsetof(type,member),val,sizeof_member(type,member))
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work. now for the real challange: can this be written in a way that doesn't require the caller to know the details of the struct (aside from the field names) ?

Comment: I can't think of a easy way to do this without knowing both the type of the struct and the field name, check the updated answer